# "make: *** No targets. Stop." when trying to auto-generate dependencies

Tags: c++, makefile

Hi I'm trying to get my makefile that can auto-generate the dependencies for simple_test. In my directory I have simple_test, simple_test.cpp, p2.h, and simple_test.out.correct.

This is what my Makefile contains:

```
DEPDIR = .d
$(shell mkdir -p $(DEPDIR) >/dev/null)
DEPFLAGS = -MT $@ -MMD -MP -MF $(DEPDIR)/$*.Td

COMPILE.c = $(CC) $(DEPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -c
COMPILE.cc = $(CXX) $(DEPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -c
POSTCOMPILE = mv -f $(DEPDIR)/$*.Td $(DEPDIR)/$*.d

%.o : %.c
%.o : %.c $(DEPDIR)/%.d
    $(COMPILE.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
    $(POSTCOMPILE)

%.o : %.cc
%.o : %.cc $(DEPDIR)/%.d
    $(COMPILE.cc) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
    $(POSTCOMPILE)

%.o : %.cxx
%.o : %.cxx $(DEPDIR)/%.d
    $(COMPILE.cc) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
    $(POSTCOMPILE)

$(DEPDIR)/%.d: ;
.PRECIOUS: $(DEPDIR)/%.d

-include $(patsubst %,$(DEPDIR)/%.d,$(basename $(SRCS)))
```

Answer (score 0):

All of your rules are pattern rules. A pattern rule cannot be the default rule. If you invoke this makefile with "make", it will complain that there are no targets-- because there are no targets.